# How to cover private static final class members by unit test exp serialVersionUID

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

I am adding unit tests to cover a legacy java projet (which i can't change),

I know how to unit test and cover this class, i did it by adding the unit test bellow.

```
public class Thing implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1463850548670691860L;

    private String id;
}
```

Unsing for example :

```
class ThingTest {

    @Test
    void testShouldNotChangeSerialVersionUID() throws NoSuchFieldException {
        final Field serialVersionUID = Thing.class.getDeclaredField("serialVersionUID");
        serialVersionUID.setAccessible(true);

        assertEquals(-1463850548670691860L, getField(serialVersionUID, new Thing()));
    }
}
```

But **sonar** and **jacoco** show serialVersionUID as not covered. which is sound.

[image]

Could you please suggest a solution to make sonar happy by covering this Field.

*Yes I know, i should not follow the tool but the practice.*

Other contraint, i can't change the visibility of serialVersionUID.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, this is just a curiosity: what is the usefulness of  having serialVersionUID covered?

Comment: the utility of adding a test for this field is to force the one who wants to modify the value to also change the test, and therefore read a message explaining to him why it is necessary to think twice before doing so, backward compatibility for example

Comment: Ensuring the `serialVersionUID` hasn't been modified would not prevent a user from modifying the class in a way that breaks serialization. If you *really* care about this, I'd recommend saving the serialized form of the object to a resource file, adding it to your `src/test/resources` directory, and writing a test that ensures the resource file can be correctly deserialized.

Comment: I agree with your that, it is possible to do so with reflection, i have unit test also for that specific case you mentioned.

Comment: Can you wrap it with a get method?

Comment: no, i can"t change src code, i can only add unit tests

Comment: I haven’t used sonar and jacoco much, but I’m having a really hard time understanding how unit testing a private constant’s value is useful.  Unit tests are supposed to test behavior.  Is this the result of a configuration file used by one of these analysis tools?  Perhaps someone put some idiotic settings in it, which you can argue should be reconsidered?  (I’ve seen some pretty bad settings in Checkstyle config files.)

Comment: Hy VGR, by default if bytecode not executed, the coverage is 0, it is possible to ignore such type of field, but i realy want to know how to cover it or get a sound explination if not possible to do it

Comment: You say, "which is sound," but it is not sound. The serialVersionUID is just a constant, and thus it produces an entry in the class's constant pool, but does not generate any bytecode instructions. Thus, there cannot be any bytecode instructions that are not covered, as a result. So this appears to be a bug in the code coverage tool.

Answer (score 0):

Your test coverage system is saying "nobody ever accesses this field during your unit tests". That's what the red bar means. So to get it to go away you need to run code that accesses that field. Using reflection to access the field to increase unit test coverage is nonsense. Even though it may turn the field green, it's not actually using the field in a meaningful way.

The right way to do this is to exercise the test class in a way that uses that field. The serialVersionUID is used during serialization/deserialization to decide if the bytes that are being read match the object that you're trying to instantiate.

Here's a simple example that covers what you want. I added an equality test at the end because that's **really** what you should be testing when you're concerned about the serialization/deserialization process.

```
package org.does.not.exist;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

class Foo implements Serializable {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;

    public Foo(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private String value;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Foo)) return false;

        Foo foo = (Foo) o;

        return value != null ? value.equals(foo.value) : foo.value == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return value != null ? value.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}

class StackoverflowTest {

    @Test
    void test() throws Exception {
        Foo foo = new Foo("a string!");

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(foo);

        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        Foo copied = (Foo) in.readObject();

        assertThat(foo).isEqualTo(copied);
    }
}
```

So do the above, but replace Foo with your own class and you should get coverage.

Comment: This doesn't test backward compatibility

Comment: @Renato Correct, it does not. It's just the minimum useful test to prove that you can use the Java language native serialization process to write out and read in the object which will get you the dumb 100% test coverage this post is asking for and actually be a meaningful test at the same time.

Comment: IMHO isn't a correct answer, this will work also if the SerialVersionUID isn't specified

Answer (score -1):

If in your JUnit you extend the ObjectInputString you can read the serialVersionUID while deserializing the object you serialized:

```
     private class MyObjectInputStream extends ObjectInputStream {

        public long uid;

        public MyObjectInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
            super(in);
        }

        @Override
        protected ObjectStreamClass readClassDescriptor() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            ObjectStreamClass readClassDescriptor = super.readClassDescriptor(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            uid = readClassDescriptor.getSerialVersionUID();
            return readClassDescriptor;
        }



    }

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
        oos.writeObject(new Thing());
        MyObjectInputStream myObjectInputStream = new MyObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));
        myObjectInputStream.readObject();
        assertEquals(-1463850548670691860L, myObjectInputStream.uid);
    }
```